# Why does "template argument deduction for class templates" not work on a plain struct?

Tags: c++, templates, standards, c++17, template-argument-deduction

> C++17 supports `template argument deduction for class templates`.
>
> Please see
>   [www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0091r3.html) for
>   detailed background information.

However, the code below doesn't work as expected;

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct A
{
    T x;
};

int main()
{
    auto p = std::pair{ 1, 2 }; // ok, as expected.

    auto a = A{ 0 };
    //
    // error : no viable constructor or deduction guide
    // for deduction of template arguments of 'A'
    //
}
```

My compiler is clang 5.0 with `-std=c++1z`.

**Why does `template argument deduction for class templates` not work on a plain struct?**

Comment: C++17 @n.m. has already changed that.

Comment: @Yakk is it there yet?

Comment: Well it looks like the error message is self-explanatory. You need either a constructor or a deduction guide. "This paper proposes extending template argument deduction for functions to *constructors of template classes*".

Comment: @n.m. Almost, sent off to ISO for standardization.  Stop asking every 5 minutes!

Comment: The information for compiler to deduct the correct type is enough. I think. Why do we need a constructor?

Comment: The compiler is not at liberty to decide when it does have enough information and when it doesn't. The standard says you need a constructor, you don't have one, so you get an error.

Comment: I just wonder: why does the standard not apply the same rule to such a common case.