# Why can't the compiler deduce the template parameter when used with a conversion operator?

Tags: c++, c++17, template-argument-deduction

Consider the following code:

```
#include <utility>

template<typename T>
struct wrapper {
    T value;
};

struct foo {
    operator wrapper<int>() {
        return{10};
    }
};


int main() {
    foo f;
    wrapper w = f; // error
    std::pair p = std::make_pair(1, 0); // ok
}
```

[gcc 7.1.1](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70facfa17b742736) fails to compile at the marked line above:

> ```
> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
> main.cpp:17:17: error: class template argument deduction failed:
>      wrapper w = f; // error
>                  ^
> main.cpp:17:17: error: no matching function for call to 'wrapper(foo&)'
> main.cpp:4:8: note: candidate: template<class T> wrapper(wrapper<T>)-> wrapper<T>
>  struct wrapper {
>         ^~~~~~~
> main.cpp:4:8: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
> main.cpp:17:17: note:   'foo' is not derived from 'wrapper<T>'
>      wrapper w = f; // error
>                  ^
> ```

`f` is convertible to `wrapper<int>`, so I expect that to happen. From there the compiler should be able to deduce that `T` is `int`. But it can't.

The compiler can deduce `std::pair`'s template parameter correctly, so I'm wondering why this isn't the case with the `wrapper`.

Any ideas?

Comment: IMO it would be confusing if class template deduction looked into conversion operators. If that's needed, one should use a explicit deduction guide.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43019240/1896169

Comment: what is this `operator struct wrapper <int> ()`? does it declare `operator wrapper` or `operator ()`?

Comment: @cat That's a conversion operator. So, technically a `operator wrapper`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For class template argument deduction, the "overload set" is composed as described in [[over.match.class.deduct/1]](http://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.class.deduct#1). Those are the following:

> A set of functions and function templates is formed comprising:
>   (1.1) - For each constructor of the primary class template designated
>   by the template-name, if the template is defined, a function template
>   with the following properties:
>   (1.1.1) - The template parameters are
>   the template parameters of the class template followed by the template
>   parameters (including default template arguments) of the constructor,
>   if any.
>   (1.1.2) - The types of the function parameters are those of
>   the constructor.
>   (1.1.3) - The return type is the class template
>   specialization designated by the template-name and template arguments
>   corresponding to the template parameters obtained from the class
>   template.
>
> (1.2) - If the primary class template C is not defined or does not
>   declare any constructors, an additional function template derived as
>   above from a hypothetical constructor C().
>
> (1.3) - An additional function template derived as above from a
>   hypothetical constructor C(C), called the copy deduction candidate.
>
> (1.4) - For each deduction-guide, a function or function template with
>   the following properties:
>   (1.4.1) - The template parameters, if any,
>   and function parameters are those of the deduction-guide.
>   (1.4.2) - The return type is the simple-template-id of the deduction-guide.

As you can see, the matching "function" in 1.1 only attempts to match the argument types to the template parameter types *exactly*. It doesn't take conversion into account (much like most other template deduction related behavior).

The reason it works for `std::pair` is due to item 1.3, and the "copy deduction candidate" it defines.